# Constrained Linear combination of learned parameters is pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have three tensors  X,Y,Z and I want to learn the optimal convex combination of these tensors wrt to  some cost, i.e.

aX + bY + cZ such that a + b + c = 1. How can I do this easily in Pytorch?

I know that I could just concatenate along an unsqueezed  axis and then apply linear  layer as  so:

```
X = X.unsqueeze(-1)
Y = Y.unsqueeze(-1)
Z = Z.unsqueeze(-1)
W = torch.cat([X,Y,Z], dim = -1)   #third axis has dimension  3)
W = torch.linear(3,1)(W)
```

but this would not apply the convex combination constraint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that works well for  those who are interested this would generalize to a linear combination of N tensors you just need to change the weights dim and number of tensors you concatenate.

```
weights = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1,3))
X = X.unsqueeze(-1)
Y = Y.unsqueeze(-1)
Z = Z.unsqueeze(-1)
weights_normalized = nn.functional.softmax(weights, dim=-1)
output = torch.matmul(torch.cat([X, Y, Z], dim=-1), weights_normalized.t()).squeeze()
```